# Angular removing cookies on leaving the website

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

I am looking for a possibility to remove all cookies if the user closes the browser window/tag. Is there any chance to trigger a event or anything else?

Comment: what happems with the case when the user may have several tabs of the same website open? why don't do a clean up on the "logout" method?

Comment: Why don't you just use session storage?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function clearCookies(){
   var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
   for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){   
      var vals =  cookies[i].split("=");
      document.cookie = vals[0] + "=;expires=Thu, 21 Sep 1979 00:00:01 UTC;";                                
   }        
}
// you will need jquery for this
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
   clearCookies()
});
```

or the clear function in angular way:

```
function clearCookies(){
    angular.forEach($cookies, function (value, key) {
       $cookieStore.remove(key);
    }); 
}
```

But if you can use session cookies (without expire value) they will be removed by the browser automatically when the user closes the browser.

Comment: The 'beforeunload' is also fired when the user reload the page. I just want to remove the cookies only if the user close the window or the tab.